# Programmatically associate a class with document 

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I want to associate my class with the document when a button is pressed. How can i do that programmatically? I've tried this method so far: [How to programmatically associate a flash .fla file with a document class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2941591/how-to-programmatically-associate-a-flash-fla-file-with-a-document-class) and compiler told me that there is no function called getDocumentDOM(). What else should i try?

Comment: while doing what you want *might* be possible with some sort of hack, it's certainly not normal.  .fla/.xfl files can only have one document class that is hardcoded in the IDE.  i believe you have a design problem.  can you give more details about what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: The link you provided, is about JSFL, that extends flash userinterface. It's not AS3 . btw, can you give an idea, why exactly you wanna have dynamic document class ?

Comment: I have a start screen in frame 1 with a start button. I want to keep my clip going from frame 2 and associate my Main class with my document when the button is pressed.

Comment: What about :
var app:MainClass;
When the user click...
app = new MainClass();
Since MainClass extends from MovieClip or Sprite you should get approximately the same result than specify MainClass as default class. But I don't see exactly where's the problem.
Both instantiate MainClass no?

Answer (score 1):

The document class is fixed, but you can easily instantiate new classes and add or remove them on the main timeline.

As someone commented, this is a design problem.  Instead of using frames on the main timeline, select the content of your first frame and convert it into a library symbol and export it for ActionScript with a class name like "StartScreen".

You can then have the constructor of your main document class call `var start_screen:StartScreen = new StartScreen(); addChild( start_screen );` to instantiate it on the main timeline.  You'll have to attach an event listener to the button, such as `start_screen.start_button.addEventListener( MouseEvent.CLICK, handler, false, 0, true );`.  Your handler function can then call `removeChild( start_screen );` and add some other content in its place.